# Make two AutoLayout constraints equal in code?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I’m pawing my way through AutoLayout for the first time (and not using IB/storyboards to do so), and I’m trying to do some simple vertical alignment in a `UITableViewCell`, of a title label and a detail label, laid out like this:

```
—————— 
Padding
Title Label
Spacing (3px)
Detail Label
Padding
——————
```

The part I’m strugging with is getting the two “Padding” constraints there to be kept equal at all times. Everything else works, but the labels are either at the very top or very bottom of the cell.

I’m actually using Masonry to implement this, and it looks like this:

```
// Constrain the title label at the top of the label container.
[title makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
    make.top.greaterThanOrEqualTo(self.contentView.top).with.priorityLow();
}];

// Constrain the detail label to the bottom of the label container.
[detail makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
    make.top.equalTo(self.titleLabel.bottom).with.offset(3).with.priorityHigh();
    make.bottom.lessThanOrEqualTo(self.contentView.bottom).with.priorityLow();
}];
```

I need the `make.top` line from the `title` constraint and the `make.bottom` line from the `detail` constraint to always maintain the same value, so that the title/spacing/detail sits in the middle.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is something you can't do just through normal constraints.

You can't make spaces equal to each other.

What you need to do is use invisible "spacer" views and make their heights equal.

So you would have something like...

```
// in pseudo VFL
V:|[topSpacer][titleLabel]-[subTitleLabel][bottomSpacer(==topSpacer)]|
```

Make the topSpacer and bottomSpacer `alpha = 0` or `hidden = YES` and it will hide them but they will act as layout scaffolding.

By doing this the gap above the titleLabel will be the same as the gap below the subTitleLabel.

Comment: Wow, is that really the easiest way? That’s a lot of faffing about for something that you’d assume would be very straightforward.

Comment: Yup, unfortunately the `spaces` in AutoLayout. i.e. the gaps between views. Are not objects themselves and so cannot be equated to anything other than a number. Of course, you could calculate the gap programmatically and update the constraints once you have calculated them but that defeats the purpose of using Auto Layout. The easiest/only way of doing this is to use invisible views as "scaffolding". It's a common technique though. Many people use it.

Comment: Yup, that initial technique there is what I was doing before the AutoLayout pangs set in. I'll give the scaffolding a go, see how obtrusive it seems. Many thanks, Sir :)

Answer (score 0):

Put your Title and Detail Labels into a subview.  Then create constraints for that subview with respect to the enclosing cell.  Since you want the top and bottom padding to be equal, you can simply choose Vertical centering as the constraint.

Also, assuming iOS 8, I believe you can allow the table cell itself to resize itself to accommodate the subview.